# Хотфиксы на странице выборов модераторов

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, выборы

Пока выборы не начались, хорошо бы исправить ошибки на странице выборов.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/1

Кодом выделил необходимые правки (полужирным не видно).

Модераторы нашего сообщества должны:

- быть терпеливым`и` и честным`и,`
- подавать личный пример`,`
- демонстрировать уважение к другим участникам сообщества и на словах, и `на деле,`
- быть готовым`и` к легкой, но строгой модерации, `способствовать` развитию сообщества, разрешать (будем надеяться) редкие споры и возражения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исправления внесены.

<sub>Удивило, что там html-разметка, а не Markdown.</sub>

Comment: А меня удивило, что страница доступна модератору. Я думал, справку и прочее только Nicolas может править)

Comment: Несколько страниц справки (вроде бы три) Николас может пометить, как доступные модераторам. Еще Тур можно править. Ну и вот выборы, как оказалось.

Comment: кстати, Тур давно пора поправить. )